# Facebook Android SDK, "Unrecognized 'com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION' extra: 'com.facebook.platform.action.request.LOGIN_DIALOG'"

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

Developing a Facebook single-sign-on app, but when testing login without the Facebook app installed, this error occurs in com.facebook.LoginActivity's authorizationClient's onCompleteListener.  There's a tiny spinning waiting dialog, then that disappears and when if I set a breakpoint in it's listener, this is the errorMessage there,

```
Unrecognized 'com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION' extra: 'com.facebook.platform.action.request.LOGIN_DIALOG'.
```

This is occurring on my Nexus 5, running 4.4.2, sdk=19.

On a Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300), running 4.1.2, sdk=19, everything occurs as expected, bringing up a web-view, and allowing you to login, and allow the app without a problem.

FacebookSDKVersion tells me it is,

```
BUILD = "3.0.0"
MIGRATION_BUNDLE = "fbsdk:20121026"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out that this happens if you try to login when you *don't* have the Facebook App installed, but *do* have the Facebook Messenger app installed.

I was just testing this on my own phone which had both installed, and I only uninstalled the main app, not even thinking about Messenger.  But obviously a call, or check goes out to see if some Facebook thing exists, which then leads the app to follow the login flow of having the app installed, but the app isn't installed, Messenger is obviously confirming something that only the main app should.

Bizarro.

Comment: Do a check yourself, see what differs between the two in their package signature with `PackageManager` and handle it manually, weird that they should have missed this

Comment: In fairness, I don't *really* have the time to do that, I'm working on something completely different and wouldn't necessarily know exactly where to look.  I tried following the login flow, but lost track with Android's crazy class and view switching system.  I've logged a bug, https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/257452847763355/ and now know what's causing it, so can message our users that are having this problem.  Also this is SDK 3.0, it may be fixed in 3.5.