# Unrecognized 'com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION' extra: 'com.facebook.platform.action.request.APPINVITES_DIALOG'

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

```
        if (AppInviteDialog.canShow())
    {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                .build();

        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(context);
        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e)
            {
                e.getMessage();
                int i = 0;
                i++;
            }
        });

        appInviteDialog.show(content);
```

### }

**onError function get errorMessage "Unrecognized 'com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION' extra: 'com.facebook.platform.action.request.APPINVITES_DIALOG'."**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675784/facebook-android-sdk-unrecognized-com-facebook-platform-protocol-protocol-act

Comment: I have read, but do not understand, Login no problem, just invite

Comment: I found some clues, when I put the facebook client replaced the old version, the invitation dialog came out.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the solution? and maybe add it as answer? are you saying that this is an issue with the Facebook for Android native app?

Comment: The problem in the SDK,you can replace the sdk version.